# Logging with filebeat - extract JSON to ES fileds

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logging, logstash, filebeat

We use filebeat + elk to handle our logs.

1. Our requirement from filebeat is to receive a json object in each line and extract the following fields:

   1. message field: The whole message that was logged.
   2. For each json field, create equivalent field in ES document.

We've tried to use `json.keys_under_root: true` but then we didn't succeed to store in 'message' field the whole content.

2. We want to have a multiline support and we didn't succeed to start the filebeat service with both `json.keys_under_root: true` and `multiline.pattern:<pattern>`definition.

Do you have any idea regarding these two issues?
We prefer to execute this json parsing using filebeat and not in logstash.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Below filebeat.yml configuration helped me to parse one-line Json log file.

filebeat.prospectors:

paths:
     your path.
     input_type: log
     json.keys_under_root: true
     json.add_error_key: true

2.) I haven't tried multiline pattern yet. You can also check https://discuss.elastic.co/t/input-multiline-json/165287 this post and other post in this forum.